# Evaluate the following complex integral in the boundary of the unit disc.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

It is known that the value of the following integral is:
$$ \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log \left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)dz=2\pi i(b-a), |b|<1, |a|<1 .$$ We calculate this using the residues at infinity.
Is there any way to calculate the following integral
 $$ \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(z) \log \left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)dz$$
for a function $f\in H(\mathbb{D})$?
I tried using the same method but I am having a trouble. Any help would be much appreciated.